# Ideal way to use jinja for file paths in XML

Tags: python, xml, jinja2

I have a working directory like the following:

```
-+ project
   -+ folder
      -+ runfile.py
      -+ template.xml
   -+ paths.py  #contains all paths referred to in runfile.py
```

I want to be able to push information to the xml file depending on the machine I am using. My plan is to use os.path to determine where the project resides on my local, and to input that path into xml using jinja.

I am a bit lost with how to implement this correctly. But this is how I have it so far:

```
# runfile.py 

from paths import item1, item2

file_loader = FileSystemLoader(os.path.join('project', 'folder'))
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)


def render_template(xml_template_name):

    template = env.get_template(xml_template_name)
    result = template.render(item1=item1, item2=item2)

result = render_template("template.xml")
```

```
# template.xml

<Block1>{{item1}}<\Block1>
<Block2>{{item2}}<\Block2>
```

Currently my problem is that the template is not recognized/cannot be found when I try to run runfile.py: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template.xml`

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `os.path.join('project', 'folder')` could be anything, depending on the directory the software was executed in.

A better bet is be absolutely sure you're in the correct path. For this, you want to get the absolute path of the current file:

```py
import os


module_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

From there, you can figure out the templates directory:

```py
templates_directory = module_directory
```

Having said that, I would **strongly encourage** you to put your templates in their own, separate directory:

```
-+ project
   -+ folder
      -+ runfile.py
      -+ templates
          -+ template.xml
   -+ paths.py  #contains all paths referred to in runfile.py
```

Then in Python:

```py
import os


templates_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'templates')

# For added measure, make sure it exists
if not os.path.exists(templates_directory):
    raise Exception(f'Templates directory does not exist: {templates_directory}')
```